# DocuSign APEX Unit Tests

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi, apex

I have written a couple of APEX Classes for use in our Salesforce Flows; and they work great.

I am now looking for some information on writing Unit Tests for the DocuSign API's.

The blog post https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-apex-toolkit-salesforce-appexchange/ makes mention of a couple of HTTP Mock Classes (https://developers.docusign.com/salesforce/apex-toolkit-reference/usermock.html) and (https://developers.docusign.com/salesforce/apex-toolkit-reference/esignatureapimock.html) however these URL's do not appear to work.

Does anyone know or have access to the Mock classes or know where I can gain access?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a documentation error. The mocks should exist in the code, look for `dfsle.UserMock` and `dfsle.ESignatureAPIMock`

But we don't yet have documentation for them. I have filed DocuSign internal bug report DFS-5699 to have this fixed.